# Adding color to br

Tags: html, css

I want to give `<br />` some color. but it is not getting applied

Here is the HTML

```
<br style="color:#EAEFF5" />
```

here is the screenshot. I want the white space to be colored

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
<div style="background-color:#EAEFF5; width:100%;" style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="2px">
<table  width="60%" cellpadding="5px" style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;"  cellspacing="1px" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th class="label" style="font-size: 120%; font-family: Courier New; text-align:center">
            Date
        </th>
        <th class="label" style="width: 7%; font-size: 120%; font-family: Courier New;text-align:center">
            Flat Status
        </th>
        <th class="label" style="width: 7%; font-size: 120%; font-family: Courier New;text-align:center">
            Comments
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" style="width: 7%; font-size: 120%; font-family: Courier New;text-align:center;">
            <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtdate" style="width: 75px;"/>
        </td>
        <td class="label" style="width: 7%; font-size: 120%; font-family: Courier New;text-align:center;">
            <%--<input id="txtcomments" type="text" runat="server" style="width: 75px;" />--%>

             <select id="ddlflatstatus" style="width: auto" name="flatstatus" runat="server">
                <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
            </select>

        </td>
        <td class="label" style="width: 7%; font-size: 120%; font-family: Courier New;text-align:center;">
            <%--<input id="txtstatusdet" type="text" runat="server" style="width: 75px;" />--%>

             <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomments" runat="server" Width="150" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

        </td>

    </tr>
</table></div>

<br style="background-color:#EAEFF5" />
```

Comment: First of all `color` won't change background. Next, I don't think you can get a cross browser background fill for `br` tag. It doesn't sound right. Can't you change your markup to avoid the `br` and use say maybe padding/margin (or) on the other hand can you not set the background color to the parent?

Comment: @Harry: so what should be done in that case ?

Comment: Wat? It's the same as trying to add color to white-space characters.

Comment: use div tag and put br tag inside <div style="background-color:red">
<br></div>

Comment: What is the common parent for the `div` above and the `br`? Can't you set the background color to it?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wj1n9pe3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In HTML, you should never add styles to a whitespace character, which is what `<br>` effectively is.

Rather use a separator:

```
<div style="height: 10px; background-color: #EAEFF5"></div>
```

Comment: I think `<br>` is 20px

Answer (score 1):

It's not guaranteed to get uniform styling for `<br>` across all the browsers so I suggest you use a `div` with empty content and style that accordingly.

```
<h1>Some Text</h1>
<div class="breaker"></div>
<p> Some Paragraph</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.breaker{
  color : red;
  border : 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom : 5px;
}
```

Here's a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQKjJg) to help you realize these changes.

Answer (score 1):

**this should work**

```
<br/>
<div style="background-color:lightgray;color:lightgray"><br/></div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't give br a color. A possible solution would be to use some a custom class on an empty element and then style that element using CSS.

For Example:

**HTML**

```
<span class="custom-br"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-br {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #cb0009; /*change color*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<br>` you can use DIV like this:

```
<div>Some text</div>
<div style="background-color:##EAEFF5;height:10px;"></div>
<div>This is under the break</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of coloring there add this

```
<div style="background-color:#EAEFF5 !important;>
```

you should use !important